# Lock screen from Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows Mobile 10

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, windows-10-mobile

I do WP 8.1 application. And cooming soon Windows Mobile 10. So, i want port my app to this platform. In my application is a function of set any image to lock screen. It work in WinPhone 8.1, but don't work in WM 10.

I use this solution for 8.1: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.phone.system.userprofile.lockscreen.setimageuri.aspx it don't work in WM 10.

And i found solution for 10: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701552.aspx but it don't work in 8.1

Is it possible to have a single assembly for both solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wp8.1 solution you link to is the silverlight version of the phone projects.   The win 10 solution does list it will work wp8.1.  You just need to use the store version of the wp 8.1 project not silverlight

Comment: Ops, I was wrong. I use WP 8.1 Silverlight. 8.1 SIlverLight and 10 don't work together?

Comment: windows;phone 8.1 had both silverlight phone and winrt versions of the phone projects.   Windows 10 does not have a silverlight ;project